# Binary to decimal converter

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion, binary

## Binary to decimal converter

As far as I can see, we don't have a simple binary to decimal conversion challenge.

---

Write a program or function that takes a positive binary integer and outputs its decimal value.

You are not allowed to use any builtin base conversion functions. Integer-to-decimal functions (e.g., a function that turns `101010` into `[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]` or `"101010"`) are exempt from this rule and thus allowed.

Rules:

- The code must support binary numbers up to the highest numeric value your language supports (by default)
- You may choose to have leading zeros in the binary representation
- The decimal output may not have leading zeros.
- Input and output formats are optional, but there can't be any separators between digits. `(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)` is not a valid input format, but both `10101010` and `(["10101010"])` are.

  - You must take the input in the "normal" direction. `1110` is `14` not `7`.

Test cases:

```
1
1

10
2

101010
42

1101111111010101100101110111001110001000110100110011100000111
2016120520371234567
```

This challenge is related to a few other challenges, for instance [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/68247/convert-a-number-to-hexadecimal), [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/63564/simplify-binary) and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69155/base-conversion-with-strings).

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/20995/34718)

Comment: Does the output have to be unsigned or can it be signed? Also, if my language happens to automatically switch between 32-bit and 64-bit integers depending on the length of the value, can the output be signed in both ranges? Eg- There's two binary values that will convert to decimal `-1` (`32 1's` and `64 1's`)

Comment: Also, can the output be floating, do does it need to be an integer?

Comment: @Carcigenicate It must be an integer, but it can be of any data type. As long as `round(x)==x` you're fine :) `2.000` is accepted output for `10`.

Comment: @milk, you may output `+42` instead of `42` if you want to. If the language support 64-bit integers without any special type casting or importing then it should behave the same for all numbers from 1 to `2^64-1`.

Comment: Can I take two parameters (the number of bits, followed by the list of bits)?  Otherwise, running a COW program will run for several minutes for anything larger than 1000000 and several hours for anything with only a couple more bits

Comment: The last number is the date the challenge was posted? The hours and seconds don't correspond with SE's UTC+0 time, it should be `20161205193745*****` :)

Comment: I _knew_ that comment would come sooner or later... Who cares about UTC+0? :)

Comment: Can we take the `0` as `\00` and `1` as `\01`?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
DḤ+¥/
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=ROG4pCvCpS8&input=&args=MTAxMDEw)

### Explanation

[image]

#### The cast

- `D` is a monad (single argument function): digits, turning `1234` into `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.
- `Ḥ` is a monad that doubles its single argument.
- `+` is a dyad (two argument function) that adds its left and right arguments.

From there, it gets a little tricky.

#### Here’s what happens at parse time

- `D`, `Ḥ`, and `+` are read. The chain looks like `[D, Ḥ, +]`.
- The next two characters are **quicks**, which act like parse-time postfix operators on the links (functions) we've read so far.
- When `¥` is read, the last two links get popped and replaced by a link that acts like the dyad formed by composing them. So now the chain looks like `[D, dyad(Ḥ+)]`.
- When `/` is read, the last link (which ought to be a dyad) gets popped and replaced by a monad that [folds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) using this dyad (intuitively: `f/` takes a list, replaces the commas in it with `f`, and evaluates the result.)
- The final chain looks like `[D, fold(dyad(Ḥ+))]`, two monads.

#### Here's what happens at run time

- Input (a number) is implicitly read into the working value (say, `101010`).
- `D` is executed, replacing the working value with its digits (`[1,0,1,0,1,0]`).
- `fold(dyad(Ḥ+))` is executed, replacing the working value with `1∗0∗1∗0∗1∗0`, where `∗` is the dyad `Ḥ+`.

#### So what does `x∗y` evaluate to?

- In a dyadic definition, the working value is initially the **left** argument, `x`.
- `Ḥ`, the **double** monad, doubles this value. The working value is now `2x`.
- `+`, the **plus** dyad, lacks a right argument, so this is a **hook**: a special syntactical pattern where the right argument of this dyad gets injected into `+`. This yields `2x + y` as the final working value, which is returned.

#### So the whole expression evaluates to:

```
1∗0∗1∗0∗1∗0 = 2×(2×(2×(2×(2×1+0)+1)+0)+1)+0
            = 32×1 + 16×0 + 8×1 + 4×0 + 2×1 + 1×0
            = 42
```

Comment: Your explanations are getting better and better :-)

Comment: Heh, I guess you do it from now on? That's awesome, +1.

Comment: I think this is the first piece of Jelly I've ever understood. +1!

Comment: Bravo. I actually understand what I initially thought was just a mess of seemingly random characters. Wonderful explanation.

Comment: Amazing, but in what encoding is that 5 bytes? Ḥ (U+1E24) is 3 bytes in UTF8 for a total of 7 bytes. If UTF16, then this is 10 bytes.

Comment: @Mark Jelly has [its own codepage](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) to make the programs look, ahem, readable, but the programs could as well just be bytestrings.

Answer (score 22):

## Python 2, <s>49</s> <s>37</s> <s>31</s> 30 Bytes

Now this will take a binary number in a decimal representation, since Python can handle arbitrarily large integers.

```python
b=lambda n:n and n%2+2*b(n/10)
```

<sup>*thanks to xnor for saving a byte :)*</sup>

The easiest way to see how this works is by seeing a basic formula for converting binary to decimal:

```python
= 101010 
= 1*(2^5) + 0*(2^4) + 1*(2^3) + 0*(2^2) + 1*(2^1) + 0*(2^0)
= 1*32 + 0*16 + 1*8 + 0*4 + 1*2 + 0*1
= 42
```

This is a 'standard' way of converting. You can expand the third line like so:

```python
= ((((1*2 + 0)*2 + 1)*2 + 0)*2 + 1)*2 + 0
```

And this is essentially what the recursive method I've made is doing.

Alternate solutions I had:

```python
b=lambda n:n and n%10+2*b(n/10)
b=lambda n:n%10+2*(n and b(n/10))
b=lambda n:0if n<1else n%10+2*b(n/10)
b=lambda n:0**(n/10)or n%10+2*b(n/10)
b=lambda n,o=0:o*(n<'0')or b(n[1:],2*o+int(n[0]))
lambda j:sum(int(b)*2**a for a,b in enumerate(j,1))
```

Comment: You can do `n%5` or `n%2` instead of `n%10`.

Comment: @xnor Ah, not sure how I missed that! Thanks :)

Answer (score 14):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

Code:

```
$¦v·y+
```

For the explantion, let's take the example **101010**. We start with the number **1** (which is represented by the first digit). After that, we have two cases:

- If the digit is a **0**, multiply the number by 2.
- If the digit is a **1**, multiply the number by 2 and add 1.

So for the **101010** case, the following is calculated:

- **1**01010, start with the number **1**.
- 1**0**1010, multiply by two, resulting into **2**.
- 10**1**010, multiply by two and add one, resulting into **5**.
- 101**0**10, multiply by two, resulting into **10**.
- 1010**1**0, multiply by two and add one, resulting into **21**.
- 10101**0**, multiply by two, resulting into **42**, which is the desired result.

Code explanation:

```
$         # Push 1 and input
 ¦        # Remove the first character
  v       # For each character (starting with the first)
   ·      #   Multiply the carry number by two
    y+    #   Add the current character (converted automatically to a number)
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=JMKmdsK3eSs&input=MTEwMTExMTExMTAxMDEwMTEwMDEwMTExMDExMTAwMTExMDAwMTAwMDExMDEwMDExMDAxMTEwMDAwMDExMQ)

Comment: Nice one! (doesn't work for 0 though I just noticed)

Comment: @Emigna Yep, luckily your code only needs to work for positive binary numbers.

Comment: Didn't even see that part. Very nice then :)

Answer (score 11):

## Turing Machine Code, 232 bytes

(Using, as usual, the morphett.info rule table syntax)

While only 40 bytes shorter than the [existing solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102258), that solution uses 12 states whereas this one only uses 4:

```
0 1 0 l 0
0 0 . r 0
0 . 1 l 0
0 _ I r 1
0 I 2 r 0
0 2 3 r 0
0 3 4 r 0
0 4 5 r 0
0 5 6 r 0
0 6 7 r 0
0 7 8 r 0
0 8 9 r 0
0 9 X l 0
0 X O r 0
0 O I r 0
1 _ _ l 2
1 * * * 0
2 * _ l 3
3 O 0 l 3
3 I 1 l 3
3 . _ l 3
3 _ * * halt
3 * * l 3
```

#### [Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?913c655ff9a63a6da93fa5af72de73cc)

The interesting computation (ie. base-conversion) actually just takes place in state 0. This state decrements the binary number one-by-one, each time incrementing a decimal counter.

Due to naming clashes of the number-bases' alphabets, I make use of `O` and `I` during the conversion. State *1,2,3* only take care of cleaning the tape, converting the symbols `O → 0` and `I → 1` and finally halting the machine.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer!

Answer (score 10):

### Haskell, <s>16</s> 111 + 57 = 168 bytes

```
import Data.String
instance IsString[Int]where fromString=map((-48+).fromEnum)
f::[Int]->Int
f=foldl1((+).(2*))
```

+57 bytes for the compile flags `-XOverloadedStrings`, `-XOverlappingInstances` and `-XFlexibleInstances`.

The challenge has some [cumbersome IO format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8077/34531), because it heavily depends on how data types are expressed in the source code. My first version (16 bytes), namely

```
foldl1((+).(2*))
```

takes a list of integers, e.g. `[1,0,1,0,1,0]` and was declared invalid because literal Haskell lists happen to have `,` between the elements. Lists per se are not forbidden. In my new version I use the very same function, now named `f`, but I overload "Quote enclosed character sequences". The function still takes a list of integers as you can see in the type annotation `[Int] -> Int`, but lists with single digit integers can now be written like `"1234"`, e.g.

```
f "101010"
```

which evaluates to `42`. Unlucky Haskell, because the native list format doesn't fit the challenge rules. Btw, `f [1,0,1,0,1,0]` still works.

Comment: Unfortunately a list is not a valid input.

Comment: @JonathanAllan: Why? And if so, how should it take input at all? In Haskell a string is just a list of characters.

Comment: I don't know why ...but I enquired about this early on and an edit was made to add "`(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)` is not a valid input format, but both `10101010` and `(["10101010"])` are." furthermore [a comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102219/binary-to-decimal-converter#comment248323_102219) suggests the array of characters is acceptable if that is how a string input is interpreted.

Comment: @JonathanAllan: my function takes a list. Lists don't have `,` between the elements. String representations of literal lists have `,` between the elements, but there are other ways where lists can come from, e.g. return values of other functions. As we don't have to take input of type string, no string representation is involved. `let list = "abc" >> fromEnum.not <$> [False ..] in foldl1((+).(2*)) list` also evaluates to `42`. The intermediate list `list` is never turned into a string, so there are no separators like `,` involved.

Comment: A list is inherently separated, it was not just the character `,` that was banned. I asked if lists were OK and the response was a comment saying the edit had been made (including "there can't be any separators between digits"), which I understood to be "No"; maybe I misunderstood, maybe @StewieGriffin could let me know.

Comment: @JonathanAllan: any "binary integer" (the input we have to take) is inherently separated, it's a sequence of powers of 2. The restriction is about explicit separators (between the digits) and not about separation. Somehow I have to take separated digits.

Comment: Note how other answers are using extra bytes to take strings or decimal representations over lists, including Lynn's Jelly answer (in Jelly a string is also just a list of characters), which would be `4` bytes not `5` with `Ḥ+¥/` rather than `DḤ+¥/`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan: the rules, as written, do not forbid lists or lists of integers, just sequences that contain additional separators between the digits. My claim as discussed above: lists don't contain separators per se. Of course the elements (here: binary digits) are separated, because we have a few of them. For example, the string `"1,0,1"` is not allowed, because it has 5 characters but only 3 digits - the other two characters are separators. -- PS: last post for today, it's already late here.

Comment: Op here: if it's possible to input `10101010` ,  `"10101010"` or something similar and make it work then the submission is valid. You may call it a string, list, integer or whatever.  Inputting `[1][0][1][0]` or `[1,0,1,0]` is not ok. Basically, it should be possible to just hit a bunch of ones and zeros in a row somewhere. Is this clear?

Comment: @StewieGriffin: better, now?

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```
s=>[...s].map(c=>r+=+c+r,r=0)|r
```

Edit: Shorter but less sweet: 2 bytes saved thanks to @ETHproductions.

Comment: As is often the case, `.map` is shorter: `s=>[...s].map(c=>+c+r+r,r=0)|r`

Comment: @ETHproductions How does your function return anything other than 0?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `s=>[...s].map(c=>r+=+c+r,r=0)|r`

Answer (score 8):

## [Labyrinth](http://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), <strike>17</strike> 15 bytes

```
-+:
8 +
4_,`)/!
```

[Try it online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=LSs6CjggKwo0XyxgKS8h&input=MTEwMTExMTExMTAxMDEwMTEwMDEwMTExMDExMTAwMTExMDAwMTAwMDExMDEwMDExMDAxMTEwMDAwMDExMQ)

[image: Image of the code]

Labyrinth is a two-dimensional, stack-based language. In labyrinth, code execution follows the path of the code like a maze with spaces acting as walls and beginning at the top-left-most non-space character. The code flow is determined by the sign of the top of the stack. Since the stack has implicit zeroes at the bottom, the first four instructions (`-+:+`) have no effect.

### Loop starting at the `,`

- `,` Push the ascii code value of the next input character to the stop of the stack, or push -1 if EOF.
- `_48` pushes 48 to the top of the stack
- `-` Pop y, pop x, push `x-y`. The previous instructions have the effect of subtracting 48 from the input yielding 0 for "0" and 1 for "1".
- `+` Pop y, pop x, push `x+y`.
- `:` Duplicate the top of the stack
- `+` This and the previous instruction have the effect of multiplying the current value by 2

So the circular part of the code, in effect, multiples the current number by 2 and adds either a 1 or a 0 depending on if the character 1 or 0 was input.

### Tail

If the top of the stack is negative (meaning EOF was found), the code will turn left at the junction (going towards the semicolon).

- ``` Negate the top of the stack to get 1
- `)` Icrement the top of the stack to get 2
- `/` Pop y, pop x, push x/y (integer division). This has the effect of undoing the last `*2` from the loop.
- `!` Output the integer representation of the top of the stack. At this point the program turns around because it hit a dead end and then exits with an error because it tries to divide by zero.

Thanks to [@Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender) for saving me 2 bytes (and teaching me how to better think in Labyrinth).

Comment: Instead of `_48-` you can simply do `#%` but unfortunately I don't see how it might help with the byte count.

Comment: You *can* save a byte with `\`)` instead of `;_2` though.

Comment: @MartinEnder, I don't understand your comment about `#%`. Can you explain how that works as a replacement for `_48-` to convert from ascii to int. Thanks for the `)` tip. I'll make that change.

Comment: At that point in your program there are always two values on the stack so `#` is just short for `_2`. While `_2%` isn't a general conversion method for ASCII to integer, it works here because you're only interested in the first two digits as possible input. An alternative would be `_1&` (since modulo 2 simply extracts the least significant bit).

Comment: Oh. That's brilliant. But yeah I'm not sure how to use that substitution (`#%`) to shorten the code overall.

Comment: The only possibility I can think of is decomposing the main loop into multiple 2x2 loops, which can often save bytes but is also usually very tricky. Not sure whether it's possible here.

Comment: Btw you also don't need the `@`. The `/` is going to terminate the program for you after the IP turns around.

Answer (score 7):

## Retina, 15 bytes

Converts from binary to unary, then unary to decimal.

```
1
01
+`10
011
1
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=MQowMQorYDEwCjAxMQox&input=MTAxMDEw)

Comment: You are not allowed to use any builtin base conversion functions. ~OP

Comment: @RomanGräf There aren't any. I was simply describing the process of my solution.

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, 44 bytes

```
for(;""<$c=$argv[1][$i++];)$n+=$n+$c;echo$n;
```

I could have sworn that I´ve seen that question before. But well.

Reads the number from left to right, shifts left and adds the current bit.

Answer (score 6):

## [Brain-Flak](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>46</s>, 28 bytes

```
([]){{}({}<>({}){})<>([])}<>
```

[Try it online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KFtdKXt7fSh7fTw-KHt9KXt9KTw-KFtdKX08Pg&input=MSAxIDAgMSAxIDEgMSAxIDEgMSAwIDEgMCAxIDAgMSAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMSAxIDEgMCAxIDEgMSAwIDAgMSAxIDEgMCAwIDAgMSAwIDAgMCAxIDEgMCAxIDAgMCAxIDEgMCAwIDEgMSAxIDAgMCAwIDAgMCAxIDEgMSA)

*Many many bytes saved thanks to @Riley!*

Since brain-flak can't take binary input, input is a list of '0's and '1's.

Explanation:

```
#Push the height of the stack
([])

#While true:
{

 #Pop the height of the stack
 {}

 #Push this top number to (the other stack * 2)
 ({}<>({}){})

 #Toggle back on to the main stack
 <>

 #Push the new height of the stack
 ([])

#endwhile
}

#Toggle back to the other stack, implicitly display.
<>
```

Comment: Love the explanation! So hard to read brain-flak without it :)

Comment: ^. I can't even read my own programs if I don't leave myself a few comments.

Comment: You can get it down to 32 bytes by getting rid of the whole if part,and  for the step "add number to other stack" just add it to the (other stack)*2. `([]){({}[()]<({}<>({}){})><>)}<>`

Comment: And you can save another 4 by just popping at the start of the while and pushing the height again at the end. `([]){{}({}<>({}){})<>([])}<>`

Comment: @Riley Oh my gosh, that's genius. Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 6):

## Java, <s>84</s> <s>79</s> <s>46</s> 48 bytes

- Version 3.1

Changed to `long`/**48** bytes:

```
s->{long x=0;for(char c:s)x=c-48l+x*2;return x;}
```

- Version 3.0

Did some golfing/**46** bytes:

```
s->{int x=0;for(char c:s)x=c-48+x*2;return x;}
```

- Version 2.0

Thanks to @Geobits!/**79** bytes:

```
s->{int i=Math.pow(2,s.length-1),j=0;for(char c:s){j+=c>48?i:0;i/=2;}return j;}
```

- Version 1.0

**84** bytes:

```
s->{for(int i=-1,j=0;++i<s.length;)if(s[i]>48)j+=Math.pow(2,s.length-i+1);return j;}
```

Comment: guess i should have done an iterative solution. lulz. good job

Comment: Is your input type List<Character> or String? If it's the latter, I was unaware Java8 could do that! If it's the former is that allowed by the challenge?

Comment: `s` should be `char[]`. I hope that's allowed...

Comment: What is the return type here? I think it should be long because "The code must support binary numbers up to the highest numeric value your language supports" per the OP but for smaller values I would think it returns an int

Comment: I think `char[]` is generally allowed as a String representation. I was just unsure because of the clarification in the OP

Comment: It returns an int. I think it costs 2 bytes to change to long.

Comment: Probably fine on input type per [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102219/binary-to-decimal-converter/102235#comment248323_102219). Might want to take the 2 byte hit for output imo

Comment: Just FYI, we can view the edit history to see previous versions of the code. You don't need to keep them all in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

## C# 6, <s>85</s> <s>37</s> 36 bytes

```
long b(long n)=>n>0?n%2+2*b(n/10):0;
```

- Thanks to [Kade](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38417/kade) for saving 41 bytes!
- Changing to C# 6 saved another 7 bytes.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://ideone.com/7bGUVz) could provide some inspiration? ;)

Comment: @Kade It does, thanks! I was looking at the Python answer which uses the same technique at the same moment you linked that :D I can get even shorter with C# 6.

Answer (score 5):

## Befunge-98, 12 bytes

```
2j@.~2%\2*+
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge-98.tryitonline.net/#code=MmpALn4yJVwyKis&input=MTEwMTExMTExMTAxMDEwMTEwMDEwMTExMDExMTAwMTExMDAwMTAwMDExMDEwMDExMDAxMTEwMDAwMDExMQ)

Reads one char at a time from input, converts it to 0 or 1 by taking its value modulo 2 (0 is char(48), 1 is char(49)), then uses the usual algorithm of doubling the current value and adding the new digit each time.

**Bonus:**
This works with any kind of input string, I've been trying for a while now to find any funny input->output combination, but I wasn't able to produce anything (sadly, "answer"=46). Can you?

Comment: LOL. I was playing the same game with my answer. Most interesting number I could generate was [666](http://befunge-98.tryitonline.net/#code=MmpALn4yJVwyKis&input=ZGV2aWwgc2F0YW4).

Comment: Nice one! I hadn't managed to find anything fitting for 666 :D It would be a lot easier if capitalization had an effect on values...

Comment: @James Holderness - I've been doing the same and I've only found 'theleapyear' to bring back 366, yours is really good.

Answer (score 4):

### Javascript (ES7) <s>41</s> <s>40</s> 36 bytes

```
f=([c,...b])=>c?c*2**b.length+f(b):0
```

takes a string as input

Shaved a byte thanks to ETHproductions

```js
f=([c,...b])=>c?c*2**b.length+f(b):0
document.write([
    f('101010'),
    f('11010'),
    f('10111111110'),
    f('1011110010110'),
].join("<br>"))
```

Comment: The right-to-left associativity of `**` is weird, but nice job using it here. `1<<b.length` would do the same thing, but it would require parentheses to keep from being parsed as `(c*1)<<(b.length+...)`. I think you can save a byte by replacing `b[0]` with `b+b` ([see here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100756/42545)).

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 25 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to @Dom Hastings.*

24 bytes of code + 1 byte for `-p` flag.

```pl
$\|=$&<<$v++while s/.$//
```

To run it:

```
perl -pe '$\|=$&<<$v++while s/.$//' <<< 101010
```

**Explanations:**

```
$\|=$&<<$v++  # Note that: we use $\ to store the result
              # at first $v=0, and each time it's incremented by one
              # $& contains the current bit (matched with the regex, see bellow)
              # So this operation sets a $v-th bit of $\ to the value of the $v-th bit of the input
while         # keep doing this while...
s/.$//        #  ... there is a character at the end of the string, which we remove.
         # $\ is implicitly printed thanks to -p flag
```

Comment: 21 bytes, [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxtZISyVGW0WtPCMzJ1WhWF9PX///f0NDQ4N/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 31 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md),  <s>9</s>   <s>7</s>  3.875 bytes

```
fṘTE
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJzPSIsIiIsImbhuZhURSIsIiIsIjEwMSJd)

```
fṘTE
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJzPSIsIiIsImbhuZhURSIsIiIsIjEwMSJd)

- -2 thanks to Steffan
- -3 chars thanks to lyxal

**Explanation:**

```python
fṘTE  # Implicit input
f     # Flatten into a list of digits
 Ṙ    # Reverse the list
  T   # Truthy indices
   E  # Two power
      # Implicit output of sum
```

Old:

```python
ṘėRvƒ↲∑    # Implicit input
Ṙė         # Reverse and enumerate
  R        # Reverse each
   vƒ      # Vecorised reduce over:
     ↲     # Left bit-shift
      ∑    # Sum
           # Implicit output
```

Comment: "You are not allowed to use any builtin base conversion functions."

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that. I've updated the answer

Comment: 7 bytes: `ṘėRvƒ↲∑` (`a*2**b` is `a<<b`, or `↲`)

Comment: `R` is "reverse each" in this case, not "reduce". `vƒ↲` is vectorized reduce over left bit-shift (it's `ƒ` not `f`)

Comment: @Steffan thanks

Comment: But the following sentence says that: Integer-to-decimal functions are exempt from this rule and thus allowed. That' a bit confusing for me Steffan.

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJzPSIsIiIsImbhuZhURSIsIiIsIjEwMSJd) for 3.875 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
RvNoy*O
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=UnZOb3kqTw&input=MTEwMTExMTExMTAxMDEwMTEwMDEwMTExMDExMTAwMTExMDAwMTAwMDExMDEwMDExMDAxMTEwMDAwMDExMQ)

**Explanation**

```
R         # reverse input
 v     O  # sum of
  No      # 2^index
     *    # times
    y     # digit
```

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 29 bytes

```
sed 's/./2*&+/g;s/.*/K&p/'|dc
```

I/O via stdin/stdout.

The `sed` expression splits the binary up into each digit and builds a RPN expression for `dc` to evaluate.

Answer (score 3):

## C, 53

```
v(char*s){int v=0,c;while(c=*s++)v+=v+c-48;return v;}
```

Same as my javascript answer

Test [Ideone](http://ideone.com/eSaKPz)

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by declaring `v` and `c` as global variables (though you need to change the name of `v`, since it's already the name of the function) like this: `w=0;c;v(char*s){while(c=*s++)w+=w+c-48;return w;}`

Comment: @Steadybox it could be `w,c;` but I don't want use globals when the answer is a function (even in code-golf)

Comment: @Steadybox Globals defaults to 0 as well, so you can drop the `=0`.

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 12 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
+%`\B
¶$`:
1
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=KyVgXEIKwrYkYDoKMQ&input=MTAxMDEw)

Alternative solution:

```
+1`\B
:$`:
1
```

#### Explanation

This will probably be easier to explain based on my old, less golfed, version and then showing how I shortened it. I used to convert binary to decimal like this:

```
^
,
+`,(.)
$`$1,
1
```

The only sensible way to construct a decimal number in Retina is by counting things (because Retina has a couple of features that let it print a decimal number representing an amount). So really the only possible approach is to convert the binary to unary, and then to count the number of unary digits. The last line does the counting, so the first four convert binary to unary.

How do we do that? In general, to convert from a list of bits to an integer, we initialise the result to `0` and then go through the bits from most to least significant, double the value we already have and add the current bit. E.g. if the binary number is `1011`, we'd really compute:

```
(((0 * 2 + 1) * 2 + 0) * 2 + 1) * 2 + 1 = 11
           ^        ^        ^        ^
```

Where I've marked the individual bits for clarity.

The trick to doing this in unary is a) that doubling simply means repeating the number and b) since we're counting the `1`s at the end, we don't even need to distinguish between `0`s and `1`s in the process. This will become clearer in a second.

What the program does is that it first adds a comma to the beginning as marker for how much of the input we've already processed:

```
^
,
```

Left of the marker, we'll have the value we're accumulating (which is correctly initialised to the unary representation of zero), and right of the value will be the next bit to process. Now we apply the following substitution in a loop:

```
,(.)
$`$1,
```

Just looking at `,(.)` and `$1,`, this moves the marker one bit to the right each time. But we also insert `` $` ``, which is everything in front of the marker, i.e. the current value, which we're doubling. Here are the individual steps when processing input `1011`, where I've marked the result of inserting `` $` `` above each line (it's empty for the first step):

```
,1011

1,011
 _
110,11
   ___
1101101,1
       _______
110110111011011,
```

You'll see that we've retained and doubled the zero along with everything else, but since we're disregarding them at the end, it doesn't matter how often we've doubled them, as long as the number of `1`s is correct. If you count them, there are `11` of them, just what we need.

So that leaves the question of how to golf this down to 12 bytes. The most expensive part of the 18-byte version is having to use the marker. The goal is to get rid of that. We really want to double the prefix of every bit, so a first idea might be this:

```
.
$`$&
```

The problem is that these substitutions happen simultaneously, so first bit doesn't get *doubled* for each bit, but it just gets copied once each time. For input `1011` we'd get (marking the inserted `` $` ``):

```
 _ __ ___
1101011011
```

We do still need to process the input recursively so that the doubled first prefix is doubled again by the second and so on. One idea is to insert markers everywhere and repeatedly replace them with the prefix:

```
\B
,
+%`,
¶$`
```

After replacing each marker with the prefix for the first time, we need to remember where the beginning of the input was, so we insert linefeeds as well and use the `%` option to make sure that the next `` $` `` only picks up things up the closest linefeed.

This does work, but it's still too long (16 bytes when counting `1`s at the end). How about we turn things around? The places where we want to insert markers are identified by `\B` (a position between two digits). Why don't we simply insert prefixes into those positions? This almost works, but the difference is that in the previous solution, we actually removed one marker in each substitution, and that's important to make the process terminate. However, the `\B` aren't character but just positions, so nothing gets removed. We *can* however stop the `\B` from matching by instead inserting a non-digit character into this place. That turns the non-word boundary into a word boundary, which is the equivalent of removing the marker character earlier. And that's what the 12-byte solution does:

```
+%`\B
¶$`:
```

Just for completeness, here are the individual steps of processing `1011`, with an empty line after each step:

```
1
1:0
10:1
101:1

1
1:0
1
1:0:1
1
1:0
10:1:1

1
1:0
1
1:0:1
1
1:0
1
1:0:1:1
```

Again, you'll find that the last result contains exactly 11 `1`s.

As an exercise for the reader, can you see how this generalises quite easily to other bases (for a few additional bytes per increment in the base)?

Answer (score 3):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 10 bytes

Takes input as a list of 0/1 on the command line: `$ pushy binary.pshy 1,0,1,0,1,0`.

```
L:vK2*;OS#
```

The algorithm really shows the beauty of having a second stack:

```
            \ Implicit: Input on stack
L:    ;     \ len(input) times do:
  v         \   Push last number to auxiliary stack
   K2*      \   Double all items
       OS#  \ Output sum of auxiliary stack
```

This method works because the stack will be doubled `stack length - n` times before reaching number `n`, which is then dumped into the second stack for later. Here's what the process looks like for input `101010`:

```
1: [1,0,1,0,1,0]
2: []

1: [2,0,2,0,2]
2: [0]

1: [4,0,4,0]
2: [2]

1: [8,0,8]
2: [2,0]

1: [16,0]
2: [2,0,8]

1: [32]
2: [2,0,8,0]

1: []
2: [2,0,8,0,32]

2 + 8 + 32 -> 42
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>27</s> <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
Fold[#+##&]
```

Accepts a `List` of bits as input (e.g. `{1, 0, 1, 1, 0}` -- *Mathematica*'s binary representation of the number `22`)

Comment: Following up from the comment on Greg's answer, how is "splitting all the digits in the input" not a base conversion function?

Comment: @MartinEnder I'm using it like the `Characters` function.

Comment: @MartinEnder Actually, as seen in [@nimi's answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102223/60043), I could just accept a list of 1s and 0s because that is the only way to represent a binary number in _Mathematica_, meaning I don't need `IntegerDigits` in the first place.

Comment: That assumes that base 10 is the "natural" representation of an integer. An actual integer value has no preferred base attached to it (I guess you could say the way it's stored is probably base 256 or maybe even base 2 but that's an implementation detail). Just because we (normally) use base 10 to write integer literals there doesn't mean integer *values* are already in base 10.

Comment: @MartinEnder [@Lynn's Jelly code](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102275/60043) uses `D`, which does the same thing as `IntegerDigits`

Comment: well then I think that's invalid too. I guess I'll ask the OP.

Comment: Actually, Dennis already did.

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102219/binary-to-decimal-converter/102223#comment248521_102223 (discussion on digit extraction built-ins is still happening)

Comment: So the result of the discussion was that `IntegerDigits` is valid but taking list input isn't.

Answer (score 3):

### R (32-bit), 64 Bytes

Input for the function should be given as character. The base functions of R support 32-bit integers.

Input:

```
# 32-bit version (base)
f=function(x)sum(as.double(el(strsplit(x,"")))*2^(nchar(x):1-1))
f("1")
f("10")
f("101010")
f("1101111111010101100101110111001110001000110100110011100000111")
```

Output:

```
> f("1")
[1] 1
> f("10")
[1] 2
> f("101010")
[1] 42
> f("1101111111010101100101110111001110001000110100110011100000111")
[1] 2.016121e+18
```

### R (64-bit), 74 Bytes

Input for the function should be given as character. The package `bit64` has to be used for 64-bit integers.

Input:

```
# 64-bit version (bit64)
g=function(x)sum(bit64::as.integer64(el(strsplit(x,"")))*2^(nchar(x):1-1))
g("1")
g("10")
g("101010")
g("1101111111010101100101110111001110001000110100110011100000111")
```

Output:

```
> g("1")
integer64
[1] 1
> g("10")
integer64
[1] 2
> g("101010")
integer64
[1] 42
> g("1101111111010101100101110111001110001000110100110011100000111")
integer64
[1] 2016120520371234567
```

Comment: You can do: `el(strsplit(x,""))` instead of `strsplit(x,split="")[[1]]` to save a couple of bytes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Especially for the `el` function - I was not aware of it.

Answer (score 3):

## Matlab, 30 Bytes

```
@(x)sum(2.^find(flip(x)-48)/2)
```

The last test case has rounding errors (because of `double`), so if you need full precision:

```
@(x)sum(2.^uint64(find(flip(x)-48))/2,'native')
```

with 47 Bytes.

Comment: I can't test this, but I believe `@(x)sum(2.^(find(flip(x)-48)-1))` will give the correct result for all cases for 32 bytes. `flip` works like `fliplr` if `x` is one dimensional.

Comment: Nice solution! I also ran into the rounding error, thanks for the fix.  What is the format of x? Calling flip or fliplr on a number just returns that number.

Comment: x is the binary string, so call it with `f=@(x)..; f('1111001010')`.

Answer (score 3):

## Elm, <s>60</s> 41 bytes

```
String.foldl(\b a->2*a+Char.toCode b-48)0
```

-19 bytes thanks to Wheat Wizard and alephalpha

You can try it [here](https://elm-lang.org/try). Here's a full test snippet:

```
import Html exposing (text)

f : String -> Int
f=String.foldl(\b a->2*a+Char.toCode b-48)0

main = text (String.fromInt (f "101010"))
```

Comment: Since you only use `n` once you can very easily express this using point free to save 4 bytes.

Comment: You can use [`String.foldl`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/1.0.5/String#foldl) instead of `List.Foldl` + `String.toList`.

Comment: You don't need to count the `f=` since the body is a valid anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v2+, 55 bytes

```
param($n)$j=1;$n[$n.length..0]|%{$i+=+"$_"*$j;$j*=2};$i
```

<s>Feels too long ...</s> Can't seem to golf it down any -- tips appreciated.

#### Explanation

```
param($n)$j=1;$n[$n.length..0]|%{$i+=+"$_"*$j;$j*=2};$i
param($n)$j=1;                                          # Take input $n as string, set $j=1
              $n[$n.length..0]                          # Reverses, also converts to char-array
                              |%{                  };   # Loop over that array
                                 $i+=+"$_"*$j;          # Increment by current value of $j times current digit
                                              $j*=2     # Increase $j for next loop iteration
                                                     $i # Leave $i on pipeline
                                                        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

### T-SQL, 202 Bytes

```
DECLARE @b varchar(max)='1',@ int=1 declare @l int=LEN(@b)declare @o bigint=CAST(SUBSTRING(@b,@l,1)AS bigint)WHILE @<@l BEGIN SET @o=@o+POWER(CAST(SUBSTRING(@b,@l-@,1)*2AS bigint),@)SET @=@+1 END PRINT @o
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 64 bytes

```
foreach(str_split(strrev($argv[1]))as$k=>$v)$t+=$v*2**$k;echo$t;
```

We reverse our binary number, split it into its component digits, and sum them based on position.

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, <s>114</s> <s>105</s> <s>63</s> 41 bytes

### V4: 41 bytes

-22 bytes thanks to @cliffroot. Since `digit` is a character, it can be converted to it's code via `int`, then have 48 subtracted from it to get the actual number. The map was also factored out. I don't know why it seemed necessary.

```clj
#(reduce(fn[a d](+(* a 2)(-(int d)48)))%)
```

### V3: 63 bytes

```clj
(fn[s](reduce #(+(* %1 2)%2)(map #(Integer/parseInt(str %))s)))
```

-42 bytes (!) by peeking at other answers. My "zipping" was evidently very naïve. Instead of raising 2 to the current place's power, then multiplying it by the current digit and adding the result to the accumulator, it just multiplies the accumulator by 2, adds on the current digit, then adds it to the accumulator. Also converted the reducing function to a macro to shave off a bit.

Thanks to @nimi, and @Adnan!

Ungolfed:

```clj
(defn to-dec [binary-str]
  (reduce (fn [acc digit]
            (+ (* acc 2) digit))
          (map #(Integer/parseInt (str %)) binary-str)))
```

### V2: 105 bytes

```clj
#(reduce(fn[a[p d]](+ a(*(Integer/parseInt(str d))(long(Math/pow 2 p)))))0(map vector(range)(reverse %)))
```

-9 bytes by reversing the string so I don't need to create an awkward descending range.

### V1: 114 bytes

Well, I'm certainly not winning! In my defense, this is the first program I've ever written that converts between bases, so I had to learn how to do it. It also doesn't help that `Math/pow` returns a double that requires converting from, and `Integer/parseInt` doesn't accept a character, so the digit needs to be wrapped prior to passing.

```clj
#(reduce(fn[a[p d]](+ a(*(Integer/parseInt(str d))(long(Math/pow 2 p)))))0(map vector(range(dec(count %))-1 -1)%))
```

Zips the string with a descending index representing the place number. Reduces over the resulting list.

Ungolfed:

```clj
(defn to-dec [binary-str]
  (reduce (fn [acc [place digit]]
            (let [parsed-digit (Integer/parseInt (str digit))
                  place-value (long (Math/pow 2 place))]
              (+ acc (* parsed-digit place-value))))
          0
          (map vector (range (dec (count binary-str)) -1 -1) binary-str)))
```

Comment: `#(reduce(fn[a b](+(* a 2)(-(int b)48)))0 %)` improved version. Moved `map` part of code directly into `reduce`, changed integer parsing method, make external function with shorthand lambda syntax.

Comment: @cliffroot `int` can be used to parse!? That'll knock off like 10 bytes in every challenge I've done here lol.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing. Taking the ascii code, then subtracting to get the value. I guess this would only work in select circumstances only. Oh well, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
PoofqWs
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=UG9vZnFXcw&input=JzEwMTAxMCc)

```
P   % Implicitly input string. Reverse
o   % Convert to array of ASCII codes
o   % Modulo 2: '1' becomes 1, '0' becomes 0
f   % Find: push array of 1-based indices of nonzeros
q   % Subtract 1 from each entry
W   % 2 raised to each entry
s   % Sum of array. Implicitly display
```

Comment: My mind went Poof!

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 32 bytes

```
f=([...n])=>n+n&&+n.pop()+2*f(n)
```

Recursion saves the day again! Though the parameterization seems a little long...

Comment: Since it's a single "argument", does `[...n]` need to be surrounded in parentheses?

Comment: @Cyoce Unfortunately, yes, or JS throws a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, <s>21</s> <s>19</s> 16 + 4 = 20 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to @Dada

Run with `-F -p` (including the extra space after the `F`).  Pipe values to the function using `echo -n`

```
$\+=$_+$\for@F}{
```

Run as `echo -n "101010" | perl -F -pE '$\+=$_+$\for@F}{'`

I feel this is sufficiently different from @Dada's answer that it merits its own entry.

Explanation:

```
-F                              #Splits the input character by character into the @F array
-p                              #Wraps the entire program in while(<>){ ... print} turning it into
while(<>){$\+=$_+$\for@F}{print}
                   for@F        #Loops through the @F array in order ($_ as alias), and...
          $\+=$_+$\             #...doubles $\, and then adds $_ to it (0 or 1)...
while(<>){              }       #...as long as there is input.
                         {print}#Prints the contents of $_ (empty outside of its scope), followed by the output record separator $\
```

This uses my personal algorithm of choice for binary-to-decimal conversion.  Given a binary number, start your accumulator at 0, and go through its bits one by one.  Double the accumulator each bit, then add the bit itself to your accumulator, and you end up with the decimal value.  It works because each bit ends up being doubled the appropriate number of times for its position based on how many more bits are left in the original binary number.

Comment: Even shorter : `perl -F -pE '$\+=$_+$\for@F}{'`

Comment: I honestly laughed at how short this is now.  Thank you.

Comment: Yea, it's pretty neat, well done!

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 12 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
(++⊢)/⌽⍎¨⍞
```

`⍞` get string input

`⍎¨` convert each character to number

`⌽` reverse

`(`...`)/` insert the following function between the numbers

`++⊢` the sum of the arguments plus the right argument

---

ngn shaved 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 31 bytes

```
f=foldl(\a b->2*a+(read$b:[]))0
```

Takes input in string format (e.g. `"1111"`). Produces output in integer format (e.g. `15`).

`:[]` Converts from an element to an array -- in this chase from `Char` to `[Char]` (`String`).
`read` Converts from string to whatever context it's in (in this case the context is addition, so converts to `Num`)

so `(read$b:[])` converts `b` from `Char` to `Num`.
`a` is the accumulator, so multiply that by two and add the `Num` version of `b`.

If input in the format `[1,1,1,1]` was allowed, the 18 byte

```
f=foldl((+).(2*))0
```

would work, but since it's not, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

## x86-16 machine code, 10 bytes

**Binary:**

```
00000000: 31d2 acd0 e811 d2e2 f9c3                 1.........
```

**Listing:**

```
31 D2       XOR  DX, DX         ; clear output value
        CHRLOOP:
AC          LODSB               ; load next char into AL
D0 E8       SHR  AL, 1          ; CF = LSb of ASCII char
11 D2       ADC  DX, DX         ; shift CF left into result
E2 F9       LOOP CHRLOOP        ; loop until end of string
C3          RET                 ; return to caller
```

Callable function, input string in `[SI]` length in `CX`. Result in `DX`.

**Example test program I/O:**

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote?  Is there a bug, issue or problem with it?

Answer (score 2):

## [7](https://esolangs.org/wiki/7), 25 bytes (65 characters)

```
07717134200446170134271600446170001755630036117700136161177546635
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcjBDcBADALBlpbYhv4rc@4iRXyGzS6JouoHuq1wHfm/oMy4oCzlBB18nLZrdsXdCw)

### Explanation

```
077                             Initialize counter to 0 (an empty section)
   17134200..77546635           Push the main loop onto the frame
```

Once the original code has finished executing, the frame is

```
||6||7134200447013427160044700017556300377700136177754635
```

The last section of this is the main loop, which will run repeatedly until it gets deleted. All of it except the last two commands is data and section separators, which push commands onto the frame to leave it as:

```
||6|| (main loop) |73426644|6734216644|6667553663||00137||54
```

**`3`** outputs the last section (`54`) and discards the last two bars. On the first iteration, `5` is interpreted as a switch to output format 5 ("US-TTY"), which converts each pair of commands to a character. The `4` following it does not form a group, so it is ignored. On future iterations, we are already in output format 5, so `54` is interpreted as a group meaning "input character". To do this, the character from STDIN is converted into its character code (or, on EOF, `-1`), and 1 is added. Then, the last section (which is now the `00137`) is repeated that many times. In summary:

- If the character is `0`, `00137` is repeated 49 times.
- If the character is `1`, `00137` is repeated 50 times.
- If there are no more characters, `00137` is repeated 0 times (i.e. deleted).
- If this was the first iteration, `00137` is left alone (i.e. repeated 1 time).

**`5`** removes the last section (`00137` repeated some number of times) from the frame and executes it, resulting in this many sections containing **`6673`**.

The main loop has now finished executing, so the last section (which is **`6673`** unless we reached EOF) runs. **`66`** concatenates the last three sections into one (and has some other effects that don't affect the number of sections), which **`73`** deletes. Thus, the last three sections are deleted, and this repeats until the last section is no longer **`6673`**.

- If we reached EOF, nothing happens.
- If this is the first iteration or the character was `0`, after removing the last three sections 0 or 16 times, there is just one copy left on the frame. This copy deletes itself and the two sections before it, leaving everything up to the main loop and the section after it.
- If the character was `1`, after removing the last three sections 17 times, all 50 copies and the third section after the main loop (the EOF handler) have been deleted.

Now, the last section left on the frame runs. This could, depending on the inputted character, be any of the three sections after the main loop.

If this is the first iteration or the character was `0`, the section just after the main loop, **`73426644`**, runs.
**`73`** deletes this section, and **`4`** swaps the main loop with the counter behind it. This counter keeps track of the number we want to output, stored as the number of `7`s and `1`s minus the number of `6`s and `0`s. This metric has the property that it is not changed by pacification (which changes some `6`s into `0`s, some `7`s into `1`s, and sometimes inserts `7...6` around code). **`2`** duplicates the counter and **`6`** concatenates the two copies (after pacifying the second, which, as we saw, does not change the value it represents), so the value is doubled. If this was the first iteration, the counter was previously empty, and doubling it still results in an empty section. Then, **`6`** gets rid of the empty section inserted by **`4`** (and pacifies the counter again, leaving the value unchanged), and **`44`** swaps the counter back to its original position. This leaves two empty sections on the end of the frame, which are removed automatically, and the main loop runs again.

If the character was `1`, the second section after the main loop (`6734216644`) runs. This is just like the section before it (explained in the last paragraph), except for two extra commands: a **`6`** at the start, which joins the section with the previous one before **`73`** deletes it, and a `1` in the middle, which adds a `7` to the counter (increasing its value by 1) after it gets doubled.

If we reached EOF, the third section after the main loop (`6667553663`) runs. **`666`** joins the last four sections (everything after the counter) into one section, to be deleted by **`3`**. `7553` exits output format 5 by outputting `55` and deletes the section before it, leaving only `||6| (counter)` on the frame. **`66`** pacifies the two sections and combines them, turning the **`6`** back into a `0` (and not changing the value of the counter). Finally, the last **`3`** outputs everything.
The `0` at the start enters output format 0 ("Numerical output"), and the rest of the section (i.e. the counter) is converted to a number by taking the number of `7`s and `1`s minus the number of `6`s and `0`s. This value, which is the input converted from binary, is output in decimal and the program terminates.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, <s>74 70</s> 55

Trailing parens already discounted. Tested in Excel Online.

### Formulae:

- `A1`: Input
- `B1`: `=LEN(A1)` (7)

#### Main Code (48):

A pretty simple "add all the powers of 2" formula:

```
=SUM(MID(A1,1+B1-SEQUENCE(B1),1)/2*2^SEQUENCE(B1))
```

Verify with:

```
=DECIMAL(A1,2)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>48</s> 37 bytes

*-11 bytes thanks to [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126)*

```r
sum(utf8ToInt(scan(,""))%%2*2^(31:0))
```

Takes input as a string, left-padded with 0s to 32 bits. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7g0V6O0JM0iJN8zr0SjODkxT0NHSUlTU1XVSMsoTsPY0MpAU/O/kgFOYAiGSv8B)

I copied some good ideas from [djhurio](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/13849)'s [much earlier R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102320/16766), so go give that an upvote too. As with the first solution there, this solution won't work for the last test case because it's too large to fit into R's default size of integer.

#### Explanation

To get a vector of the bits as integers 0 and 1, we use `uft8ToInt` to convert to a vector of character codes. This gives us a list of 48s and 49s, which we take mod 2 to get 0s and 1s.

Then, to get the appropriate powers of 2 in descending order, we construct a range from 31 down to 0. Then we convert each of those numbers to the corresponding power of two (`2^`).

Finally, we multiply the two vectors together and return their `sum`.

Comment: [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7g0V6O0JM0iJN8zr0SjODkxT0NHXV1TU1XVSMsoTsPY0MpAU/O/kgFOYAiGSv8B) (or [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qflJmXWFRp@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNJs7g0V6O0JM0iJN8zrwTIV1U10jKK0zA2tDLQ1IRq0FAywAkMwVBJ8z8A) as a function) thanks to 'You may choose to have leading zeros in the binary representation'.  Accepts input as 32-bit binary string, with leading zeros, but easily modified to double-integer precision for the same length code...

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
(+/2 1*,)/
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs9LQ1jdSMNTS0dTn4tLnMuQyNABBLkMgCQFgPpACkxAMIQzAGCRrgBAD01wxXFyeVnrq6sbxGjUxlka2WlbqmvEGVgmJRellCoZcaeqeXABdSRgX)

Answer (score 2):

### C, 48 bytes

```
i;f(char *s){for(i=0;*++s;i+=i+*s-48);return i;}
```

Heavily inspired by @edc45 's answer but I made some significant changes. I made 'i' a global variable to save having to typecast. I also used a for loop to save a few bytes. It does now require a single leading 0 in the binary representation.

**More readable version**

```
f(char *s){
  int i = 0; // Total decimal counter
  for(;;*++s;i+=i+*s-48); // Shift left and add 0 or 1 depending on charecter
  return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## k, 8 bytes

Same method as the Haskell answer above.

```
{y+2*x}/
```

Example:

```
{y+2*x}/1101111111010101100101110111001110001000110100110011100000111b
2016120520371234567
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 87 bytes

```java
long c(String b){int a=b.length()-1;return a<0?0:b.charAt(a)-48+2*c(b.substring(0,a));}
```

For some reason I always go straight to recursion. Looks like an [iterative solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102233/51785) works a bit nicer in this case...

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>56</s> 47 bytes

Reverses a binary string, then adds each digit's value to the sum.

```
n=>[...n].reverse().reduce((s,d,i)=>s+d*2**i,0)
```

**Demo**

```js
f=n=>[...n].reverse().reduce((s,d,i)=>s+d*2**i,0)
document.write( f('101010') ) // 42
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>8</s>, 7 bytes

```
"@oovsE
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=IkBvb3ZzRQ&input=JzEwMTAxJw)

One byte saved thanks to @LuisMendo!

[Alternate approach: (9 bytes)](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=b290bjpQVypz&input=JzEwMTAxJw)

```
ootn:PW*s
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, <s>18</s> 83 bytes

<s>`f=n=>parseInt(n,2)`</s>

`f=n=>n.split('').reverse().reduce(function(x,y,i){return(+y)?x+Math.pow(2,i):x;},0)`

**Demo**

```js
f=n=>n.split('').reverse().reduce(function(x,y,i){return(+y)?x+Math.pow(2,i):x;},0)
document.write(f('1011')) // 11
```

Comment: Uses a built-in, which is disallowed.

Comment: @TuukkaX Ah, missed that. Thanks.

Comment: I was just about to do the same thing (in c#), I'm bad at reading.

Comment: It's a code golf challenge, try to write short code. `(y==='1')` could be `+y`

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 38

Simple is better

```
s=>eval("for(i=v=0;c=s[i++];)v+=+c+v")
```

**Test**

```js
f=s=>eval("for(i=v=0;c=s[i++];)v+=+c+v")

console.log("Test 0 to 99999")
for(e=n=0;n<100000;n++)
{  
  b=n.toString(2)
  r=f(b)
  if(r!=n)console.log(++e,n,b,r)
}
console.log(e+" errors")
```

Answer (score 1):

## Turing Machine Code, 272 bytes

(Using, as usual, the morphett.info rule table syntax)

```
0 * * l B
B * * l C
C * 0 r D
D * * r E
E * * r A
A _ * l 1
A * * r *
1 0 1 l 1
1 1 0 l 2
1 _ * r Y
Y * * * X
X * _ r X
X _ _ * halt
2 * * l 2
2 _ _ l 3
3 * 1 r 4
3 1 2 r 4
3 2 3 r 4
3 3 4 r 4
3 4 5 r 4
3 5 6 r 4
3 6 7 r 4
3 7 8 r 4
3 8 9 r 4
3 9 0 l 3
4 * * r 4
4 _ _ r A
```

AKA "Yet another trivial modification of my earlier base converter programs."

[Try it online](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?a283209e440e64106cd35d1bc3f181e1), or you can also use test it using [this java implementation.](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Turing-Machine)

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge, <s>20</s> 18 bytes

Input must be terminated with EOF rather than EOL (this lets us save a couple of bytes)

```
>+~:0`v
^*2\%2_$.@
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=Pit-OjBgdgpeKjJcJTJfJC5A&input=MTEwMTExMTExMTAxMDEwMTEwMDEwMTExMDExMTAwMTExMDAwMTAwMDExMDEwMDExMDAxMTEwMDAwMDExMQ)

**Explanation**

```
>             The stack is initially empty, the equivalent of all zeros.
 +            So the first pass add just leaves zero as the current total. 
  ~           Read a character from stdin to the top of the stack.
   :0`        Test if greater than 0 (i.e. not EOF)
      _       If true (i.e > 0) go left.
    %2        Modulo 2 is a shortcut for converting the character to a numeric value.
   \          Swap to bring the current total to the top of the stack.
 *2           Multiply the total by 2.
^             Return to the beginning of the loop,
 +            This time around add the new digit to the total.

                ...on EOF we go right...
       $      Drop the EOF character from the stack.
        .     Output the calculated total.
         @    Exit.
```

Comment: I had like a 60-something byte code that was dealing with integers, and wow, this is so much more simple and elegant. Great job, and nice explanation too.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 37 bytes

```
ruby -e 'o=0;gets.each_byte{|i|o+=o+i%2};p o/2'
         1234567890123456789012345678901234567
```

This depends on the terminating `\n` (ASCII decimal 10) being zero modulo 2 (and on ASCII 0 and 1 being 0 and 1 mod two, respectively, which thankfully they are).

Answer (score 1):

## [아희(Aheui)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Aheui), 40 bytes

```
아빟뱐썩러숙
뎌반뗘희멍파퍄
```

Accepts a string composed of 1s and 0s.

**To try online**

Since the online Aheui interpreter does not allow arbitrary-length strings as inputs, this alternative code must be used (identical code with slight modifications):

Add the character `벟` at the end of the first line (after `우`) length(n)-times.

```
어우
우어
뱐썩러숙
번댜펴퍼망희땨
```

If the input is `10110`, the first line would be `어우벟벟벟벟벟`.

When prompted for an input, do NOT type quotation marks. (i.e. type `10110`, not `"10110"`)

[Try it here! (copy and paste the code)](http://jinoh.3owl.com/aheui/jsaheui_en.html)

Answer (score 1):

## ClojureScript, 36 bytes

```
(fn[x](reduce #(+(* 2 %)(int %2))x))
```

or

```
#(reduce(fn[a n](+(* 2 a)(int n)))%)
```

The straightforward reduction.  Takes a string as input.

Answer (score 1):

## Minkolang v0.15, <s>23</s> 19 bytes

```
n6ZrI[2%2i;*1R]$+N.
```

[Try it online!](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=n6ZrI%5B2%252i%3B*1R%5D%24%2BN%2E&input=1101)

#### Explanation

```
n                             gets input in the form of a number
 6Z                           converts to string (so that it is split into an array)
   r                          reverses it
    I                         gets the stack length
     [        ]               for loop with the stack's length as the number of iterations
      2%                       gets the modulo of the ascii value
                               1 =(string conversion)> 49 =(after modulo)> 1
                               0 =(string conversion)> 48 =(after modulo)> 0
        2i;                    raises 2 to the power of the loop counter
           *                   multiplies it by the modulo
            1R                 rotates stack 1 time
              $+              sums everything
                N.            outputs as number and exit
```

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, <del>99</del> <del>88</del> 72 bytes

Takes a string as input

```
(defun f(s)(reduce(lambda(a d)(+ d(* a 2)))(map'list #'digit-char-p s)))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(defun bin-to-dec (bin-str)
  (reduce (lambda (acc digit) (+ digit (* acc 2)))
          (map 'list #'digit-char-p bin-str)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## ><> (Fish) <s>36</s> 28 bytes

```
/i:1+?!v$2*$2%+!| !
/0| ;n~<
```

Edit 1: Forgot to put the output in the original. Added output and used MOD 2 instead of minus 48 to convert ascii to decimal to save the extra bytes lost. (no change in bytes)

Edit 2: Changed the algorithm completely. Each loop now does this; times current value by 2, then add the mod of the input. (saving of 8 bytes)

[Online version](https://fishlanguage.com/playground/BPT5uHb6PgvsRyvrP)

[Try it Online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=L2k6MSs_IXYkMiokMiUrIXwgIQovMHwgO25-PA&input=MTEwMTExMTExMTAxMDEwMTEwMDEwMTExMDExMTAwMTExMDAwMTAwMDExMDEwMDExMDAxMTEwMDAwMDExMQ) - This works with bigger numbers than the above link.

Answer (score 1):

## **C, 44 bytes**

```
d(s,v)char*s;{return*s?d(s,v+=v+*s++-48):v;}
```

Use as follows :

```
int main(){
  printf("%i\n", d("101010",0));
}
```

Remove two bytes and an unused parameter thanks to Steadybox

Comment: You have an unused parameter `c` there. Removing it saves two bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>41</s> 37 bytes

```c
i;b(char*s){i+=i+*s++%2;i=*s?b(s):i;}
```

[Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HSeSFhE9lswSnFlj)

Answer (score 1):

## **MATLAB, 49 bytes**

```
@(a)dot(int2str(a)-'0',2.^(floor(log10(a)):-1:0))
```

Anonymous function that splits the input into an array with `int2str(a)-'0'`, then does a dot product with powers of 2. Has rounding error for the last test case, will update the solution when I figure out a fix.

Answer (score 1):

## Forth (gforth 0.7.3), 47 bytes

```
: x 2 base ! bl parse s>number drop decimal . ;
```

`: x` - define new word with name 'x'
`2 base !` - set base to binary
`bl parse` - read line until a space (bl) or EOL
`s>number` - try to convert the string to number
`drop` - we only want the converted number and not the success flag
`decimal` - set base to decimal
`.` - print value on top of stack
`;` - end of definition

Test cases:

```
x 1 1  ok
x 10 2  ok
x 101010 42  ok
x 1101111111010101100101110111001110001000110100110011100000111 2016120520371234567  ok
```

Comment: Sorry, forget my last comment, I thought this answer was to another challenge :/ The answer is perfectly valid :)

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, <s>47</s> 44 bytes

```
INPUT B$WHILE""<B$N=N*2+VAL(SHIFT(B$))WEND?N
```

Another program of the same size:

```
INPUT B$WHILE""<B$N=N*2OR"0"<SHIFT(B$)WEND?N
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 26 chars, 52 bytes

```
{+/a×⌽1,2x*⍳¯1+≢a←1-⍨⎕D⍳⍵}
```

test:

```
  f←{+/a×⌽1,2x*⍳¯1+≢a←1-⍨⎕D⍳⍵}
  ⎕fmt f"0"
0
~
  f"1"
1
  ⎕fmt f"101010"
42
~~
  f"10"
2 
  (≢,f)"11011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
152 4995366924470859583704000893073232977339613183
```

152 bits... It should be limited from memory for store string and numbers.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>17</s> 14 bytes

```
$+(**_*BMERVa)
```

Doesn't work on TIO because unary ** is only in the latest Pip version.

[image]

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fRVtDSytey8nXNSgsUfP///@GhgaGEGAAhoYGYBKCIYQBGINkDRBiYPq/bgEA)

Comment: Following my own tips, Isee.

Comment: That's 2 of the 3 bytes I saw, and unary `**` is another I wasn't including, but there's still one more. (It's one of my tips.) Also, `BMER` doesn't work because it scans as `BM ER` not `B ME R`.

Comment: can't seem to find it yet lol

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 18 + 1 (`-p`) = 19 bytes

Combines techniques from the other Perl entries.  Scored using the rules at the time of posting.

```perl
s/./$\+=$\+$&/ge}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX09fJUbbFohV1PTTU2ur//83NDQ0@JdfUJKZn1f8X7cAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>28</s> 26 bytes

-2 bytes thank to l4m2!

```javascript
f=n=>n%2|(n<2?0:2*f(n/10))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P802z9YuT9WoRiPPxsjewMpIK00jT9/QQFPzf0FRZl6JRpoGkM0FYxsis1EkUGXQeKh8KABaAQA)

Takes input as a Number, outputs a Number.

Comment: https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P802z9YuT9WoRiPPxsjewMpIK00jT9/QQFPzf0FRZl6JRpoGkM0FYxsis1EkUGXQeKh8KABaAQA

Answer (score 1):

## ARM Thumb-2 machine code, 16 bytes

```
2100 f810 2b01 b112 0852 4149 e7f9 4770
```

Commented assembly:

```c
        .syntax unified
        .arch armv6t2
        .thumb
        .globl bin2int
        .thumb_func
        // Input: null terminated string in r0
        // Output: integer in r1
bin2int:
        // Set initial result to zero
        movs    r1, #0
.Lloop:
        // Load char from r0 into r2, increment
        ldrb    r2, [r0], #1
        // Was it '\0'? If so, bail.
        cbz     r2, .Lend
        // Shift the lowest bit into the carry flag
        // ASCII '0' has the lowest bit clear, ASCII '1'
        // does not.
        lsrs    r2, r2, #1
        // Multiply the result by 2 (by adding to itself),
        // and add the carry flag to that result
        adcs    r1, r1
        // Jump back to .Lloop (our loop condition is cbz)
        b       .Lloop
.Lend:
        // Return
        bx      lr
```

The input is a null terminated string in `r0` and the output is in `r1`.

I came up with the same idea as 640KB (`SHR/ADC`, or in my case, `lsrs/adcs`) without even seeing their solution.

Great minds think alike, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
Fo+Dd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8b9bvrZLyv///6MNdQwNgAgEdQyBJASA@UAKTEIwhDAAY5CsAUIMTMcCAA)

```
F        # Fold from left
         # (apply binary function to each element,
         # together with the value of the previous result)
    d    # over all the digits of the input,
         # with this function:
 o       # o = combination of 2 functions
  +      # add second argument (each new digit, from left) to   
   D     # double the first argument (previous result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [FunStack](https://github.com/dloscutoff/funstack) alpha, 31 bytes

```
Plus Double compose foldl1 Odd?
```

Takes a string consisting of `0`s and `1`s, outputs an integer. Try it at [Replit](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/funstack): pass the input string as a command-line argument (formatted like `\"1101\"`) and enter the program on stdin.

#### Explanation

Same idea as [Steffan's Elm answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256541/16766), [Dominic van Essen's Husk answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218275/16766), etc.

```
Plus Double compose
```

Push the functions `Plus` (dyadic, adds its arguments) and `Double` (monadic, doubles its argument. Compose them, resulting in a dyadic function that doubles its first argument and adds the result to its second argument.

```
foldl1
```

Perform a left fold over a list using that function, with the first element of the list serving as the initial accumulator value. This errors if the list is empty, but we don't have to worry about that since the input represents a positive integer.

```
Odd?
```

The list that we want to fold over is the program argument (a string, aka list of characters) with the character `'0'` turned into the number `0` and similarly for `'1'` and `1`. The obvious way to do this is `Minus '0'`, but since we only have to deal with `0` and `1`, we can use `Odd?` instead. This function returns `1` if its argument is odd and `0` if it is even; when applied to characters, it considers whether the charcode is odd or even.

---

Another 31-byte answer is possible using a different approach:

```
Sum Times Pow 2 #N Reverse Odd?
```

This generates an infinite list of powers of 2, multiplies it by the input digits reversed, and sums the result.

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 70 bytes

```go
func(s string)(o uint64){for _,r:=range s{o=2*o+uint64(r-'0')}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY9NCsIwEIX3OUXsxsTfJK2tCN269gYSxJSiTWSauik9iZsieApP4m1sk4roDDMP3hfekNs9M-1rdJGHk8yOuJC5RnlxMWAXgSpsgNBVAlbpo7Jqvn5tVaUPpMSlhVxnlBhc5drGEa2VAbyfwSYFqbugsjapmJipxwTmYzamDYKjrUA3Q9qzT3M3CcU12nWZ9qyJIgEPKEXLJebox2WDLf7svgcU_bEO-XKPOnHbj1_MTU_Z13P6ucZ4zAVbCRYmXITRKk7Q8IW29foG)

Takes in a string of binary digits (`01`). For each digit, convert it to it's corresponding number, and add it to twice the total.

Comment: `r-'0'` -> `r&1`

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 31 bytes

```arturo
f:$[n][(n>0)?[+2*f n/10n%2]->0]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?et6Jlx)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, <s>51</s> 48 bytes

```
=NPV(-0.5,MID(n,SORT(SEQUENCE(LEN(n)),,-1),1)/2)
```

*Input **n***

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 51 bytes

```
f(n)=∑_{i=0}^{log(n+0^n)}2^imod(floor(n/10^i),10)
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iycp3mnk5v)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/leowakf0w6)

Without the ban on binary list input, this could be **33 bytes**:

```
f(l)=total(2^{[l.length-1...0]}l)
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/j38h6yyqkf)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lkegkzrc5l)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
drVO
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UrBS7IKlpSVpuhZLUorC_JcUJyUXQwUWLDM0AEEIDwA)

##### Explanation

```python
drVO  # Implicit input  -> 101010
d     # Cast to digits  -> [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
 r    # Reverse         -> [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
  V   # Truthy indices  -> [1, 3, 5]
   O  # Two power       -> [2, 8, 32]
      # S flag sums     -> 42
      # Implicit output
```

Old:

```python
dŻrO×  # Implicit input  -> 101010
d      # Cast to digits  -> [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
 Ż     # Length range    -> [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  r    # Reverse         -> [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]  [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
   O   # Two power       -> [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]  [32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
    ×  # Multiply        -> [32, 0, 8, 0, 2, 0]
       # S flag sums     -> 42
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## Commodore C64 BASIC, 84 BASIC Bytes

```
0inputa$:b=len(a$):ifb=.thenend
1t=.:c=t:forx=bto1step-1:c=c+1:t=t+val(mid$(a$,c,1))*2^(x-1):next:?t
```

### How it works

Firstly, the `inputa$` is expecting the user to enter a string, though the only sanity check is that there is something is entered. We then initialise three variables, `b` to the string length, `t` to zero (in the Commodore BASIC interpreter, parsing `.` is slightly quicker than parsing `0`), and `c` also to zero. As we enter the loop, we read each position from right to left.

For each position, the value in `c` is incremented by 1, and `t` adds the value of each position multiplied by 2 the power of the current bit position minus 1, and it continues until each position is calculated. The result is then printed.

[image: Binary to decimal converter, Commodore C64]

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
1QY_%0m@s
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=1QY_%250m%40s&input=101010)

```
 QY_      -    reverse digits input
1   %     -   get indecies with a value of 1
     0m@  -  map(set_nth_bit(0, i), ^)
        s - sum(^)
```

Also 9 bytes

```
Y_'XltV}+
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=Y_%27XltV%7D%2B&input=101010)

```
Y_        - reverse digits
  'Xlt    - splat(^), len(^)-1
      V   - repeat length times:
       }+ -  double and add to stack
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
DLḶ2*U,DPS
```

You know your Jelly code is still golfable when it's above 7 bytes...

```
It basically consists of two parts
   2*       generate a list of the powers of two
 LḶ         for all the powers of 2 from 0 to the length of the binary input
D           Convert the binary string into a list to get its length with L   
     U      Then upend that list (for '101010', we now have a list of [32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
      ,     Combine this list
       D    with the individual digits of the input  
        P   multiply them with eah other [32*1, 16*0, 8*1, 4*0, 2*1, 1*0]
         S  And sum the result      42 =   32 +  0  +  8 +  0 +  2 +  0
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=REzhuLYyKlUsRFBT&input=&args=MTAxMDEw)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 44 bytes

```
2^Range[Length[d=IntegerDigits@#]-1,0,-1].d&
```

Unnamed function taking an integer argument (interpreted as a base-10 integer, but will only have the digits 0 and 1) and returning an integer. `d` is set equal to the set of digits, and then the dot product of d with the appropriate sequence of powers of 2 generates the value.

Comment: "You are not allowed to use any builtin base conversion functions." I'd consider `IntegerDigits` one of those.

Comment: @MartinEnder I think he's using `IntegerDigits` just to split all the digits in the input. The conversion part is done by `2^Range[...].d`

Comment: In any case, JHM's answer is way better than mine :) so let's contemplate the use of `IntegerDigits` over there. If it's disallowed, JHM and I will presumably use the same string-based preprocessing step, and the other answer will still be better!

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 35 bytes

```
f=([c,...b],n=0)=>c<2?f(b,+c+n+n):n
```

For `c='1'` and `c='0'`, `c<2` returns true.
If `b` is empty, `c` will be undefined in the next recursion and `c<2` will be `false`.

Comment: Hehe ... the 35th answer has 35 bytes. :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.5](http://julialang.org/), 22 bytes

```julia
!n=n>0&&2*!(n÷10)|n&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#RYk7CoAwEER7T7EJGBJJsbFXPEhKDaQZRSy9lwfwYDGfwlnePJhNAhNmVmochMb7ODY3lEthPwkUQdpZclwol53VUoes2o1WXClf/rdq01HOcpwRV9CyXz0KHtISLAmYbsOaPg)

Answer (score 0):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-rr`,  <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
0&÷^⑷2⑻Ë*⑹⑸⅀
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fQO3w9rhHE7cbPZq4@3C31qOJOx9N3PGoteH/f0MDEPyvW1QEAA)

### Explained

```
0&              # Place 0 into the register. This will serve as the power to which 2 will be raised
  ÷^            # Take the input as a number and split it into it's individual numbers. It is then reversed.
    ⑷           # Start a map applying the following to each item in the input:
      2⑻Ë*      #   Exponate 2 to the power of the register and multiply the number by that value
          ⑹     #   Increment the register
           ⑸⅀  # Close the map and sum the stack, printing that sum implicitly
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Ô¬ËÑpE
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=1KzL0XBF&input=IjEwMTAxMCI)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╖~♫p
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b77e0e70&i=1%0A10%0A101010%0A1101111111010101100101110111001110001000110100110011100000111&m=2)

same reducing idea as Jelly.

Answer (score 0):

## [Raku](https://raku.org), 33 bytes

```
{.flip.comb.kv.map(2*** * *).sum}
```

(If builtins were allowed, this would just be `.parse-base(2)`.)

Explanation:

`.flip` reverses the string, `.comb` converts it into a list of chars, `.kv` inserts the index of each char in front of it. The `map` block consumes two elements at a time, computing the product of 2 to the power of the first argument (the index) all multiplied by the second argument (the 0 or 1), and the resulting list of products is totaled by `.sum`.

The asterisks in the `map` call are doing triple duty: the first two are the exponentiation operator, while the third is a `Whatever` standing for the first argument to the block (and is the reason the expression becomes a block without curlies). Likewise, the fourth is the standard ASCII multiplication operator, while the fifth is another `Whatever` representing the second argument. So this ungolfed version does the same thing:

```
… .map( { 2**$^k × $^v } ) …
```

[Try it online!](https://glot.io/snippets/ghddfgc9du)

Answer (score 0):

## shell with `dc`, <s>16</s> <s>13</s> 10 bytes

There's already a [`bash` + GNU utils](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102230/104387), but this solution is POSIX compliant and shorter.

```shell
dc -e "10o2i$1p"
```

It's also a bit quicker (we use internal functioning instead of extra computation, plus there's only one process call instead of two.) But, quoting and extra spaces aren't mandatory

```shell
dc -e10o2i$1p
```

Now, explanation of the expression (`-e` argument)

1. `10 o` ask to set Output base to decimal.
2. `2 i` ask to set Input base to binary.
   Note that the order matters here.
   If we issue first `2i`, `10o` would be read as request to set to binary…
3. `$1 p` ask to Print out the entry…
   Read then as binary and expressed in decimal form.

Better, on standard installations with no `DC_ENV_ARGS` or others (depending your implementation) variable set, default base is decimal. So, finally

```shell
dc -e2i$1p
```

Note : `dc` is a big bases-converter where `i` tells how to parse inputs (kinda `scanf()`) and `o` tells how to display it (kinda `printf()`). Values are always stored and manipulated using DCB representation.

Comment: But the instructions say “You are not allowed to use any builtin base conversion functions.”

Comment: So the whole command should be discard (in bash answer too): the command is a base conversion itself, but it's not a shell builtin.

Comment: It’s not a big deal to me one way or another but I think the point is to do the math operations explicitly.  They don’t mention the shell at all, just “builtin” which I assume refers to built in functionality to perform these math operations.  Maybe ask for clarification.

Comment: "the point is to do the math operations explicitly." That's a better mention than "You are not allowed to use any builtin base conversion functions." because I just avoid the shell stuff `$((2#$1))` and even for `dc` external command, the `i` function is a kinda "Integer-to-decimal functions" :s

Comment: I may be misreading it, but that's how I understood it.

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 29 bytes

```
sum(seq(sub(Ans,length(Ans)-I,1)2^I,I,0,length(Ans)-1
```

Takes input as a string in `Ans`.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 54 bytes

Solution using Streams only :

```java
s->s.chars().mapToLong(e->e).reduce(0,(a,b)->2*a+b-48)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVBNa8MwDD0vv0L0ZG@18cYOg9H8gvTU3cYOiuO07pwPbKcwSn97pjqGnUaekWT0pOeHz3hBcW6@53GqndWgHYYAe7Q9XIsCCLaPxreoDVTUggw39Edo2SF6S5fA3xNzW1ZCxEhaFTjYzUGUQeoT@sC47HD8GCraZUaUhktvmkkbprYMtzUX5csjPtXi9Y3Pi2B2lQUvg22gI2/53c8vQH8M/Fo8HH5CNJ0cpihHoqLrmZMt26gNJ2//0s8r9Nq6up@VGRpZkIappLzEklSKO6v@eqkm6fyzt/kX)

---

If the question didn't require a long, the answer could have been shorter and more elegant (**38 bytes**) :

```java
s->s.chars().reduce(0,(a,b)->2*a+b-48)
```