# Diluted Integer Sums

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, number-theory, binary

A positive integer can be *diluted* by inserting a `0` between two bits in its binary expansion. This means that an `n`-bit number has `n-1` dilutions, which are not necessarily all distinct.

For example, for `12` (or `1100` in binary), the dilutions are

```
11000 = 24
   ^

11000 = 24
  ^

10100 = 20
 ^
```

In this challenge, we're going to be taking the sum of all the dilutions, exclusive of the original number. For `12`, taking the sum of `24, 24, 20` results in `68`, so `68` should be the output for `12`.

#### Challenge

Given a positive integer `n > 1` as input, output/return the diluted sum as explained above.

#### Examples

```
in    out
---   ---
2       4
3       5
7      24
12     68
333  5128
512  9216
```

#### Rules

- The input and output can be assumed to fit in your language's native integer type.
- The input and output can be given in [any convenient format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Does "any convenient format" include a binary string?

Comment: @Shaggy "Any convenient format" is intended to be inclusive of *methods* of input/output, not *format*. As such, I'm going to say no, you must take input as an integer or a string representing that integer.

Comment: Nice challenge!

Comment: This sequence is currently (30 Jan 2018) [not in the OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=4%2C5%2C16%2C18%2C22%2C24%2C48%2C51%2C56&sort=&language=english&go=Search)

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>43</s> 39 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=2:n/i and n*2-n%i+f(n,i*2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcjBCkBAEAbgu6f4L5tdRjKb1JaHWWkzxRAunn5x@/qO51525ZzTuMZtmiOUZOSgrSDqDK24USN1st9X7HLaTwhEwQRPGAjdL/@57zgUwHGK3iiNvwLMVRorhGTFufwC)

---

### How?

Each call of the recursive function calculates a single dilution. The position of the inserted `0` is `log2(i)`. The function recurses until `i` gets bigger than `n` and the insertion would be on the left of the number. If `i>n`, `n/i` evaluates to `0`, which is a falsy value in Python.

`n*2` shifts the entire number one binary digit left, `n%i` or `n % 2**(position of insertion)` calculates the value of the part that should not be shifted left. This value gets subtracted from the shifted number.

### Example (n=7)

```python
call       n/i          bin(n)  n*2     n%i   dilution       return value

f(7, i=2)  3 => truthy  0b111   0b1110  0b1   0b1101 = 13    13 + f(7, 2*2) = 13 + 11 = 24
f(7, i=4)  1 => truthy  0b111   0b1110  0b11  0b1011 = 11    11 + f(7, 4*2) = 11 + 0 = 11
f(7, i=8)  0 => falsy                                        0
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
BJṖ2*ɓdḅḤ}S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/J6@HOaUZaJyenPNzR@nDHktrg/0f3HG5/1LTG/f9/Ix0FYx0Fcx0FQxDLGMg2NTQCAA)

#### How it works

```
BJṖ2*ɓdḅḤ}S  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

B            Binary; convert n to base 2. This yields a digit array A.
 J           Indices; yield [1, ..., len(A)].
  Ṗ          Pop; remove the last element, yielding [1, 2, ..., len(A)-1].
   2*        Elevate 2 to these powers, yielding [2, 4, ..., 2**(len(A)-1)].
             Let's call the result B.
     ɓ       Begin a new, dyadic chain, with left argument n and right argument B.
      d      Divmod; yield [n/b, n%b], for each b in B.
        Ḥ}   Unhalve right; yield 2b for each b in B, i.e., [4, 8, ..., 2**len(A)].
       ḅ     Unbase; convert each [n/b, n%b] from base 2b to integer, yielding
             (2b)(n/b) + (n%b).
          S  Take the sum.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 13 bytes

```
tZl:W&\5ME*+s
```

Try it at [MATL Online!](https://matl.io/?code=tZl%3AW%26%5C5ME%2a%2Bs&inputs=333&version=20.6.0) Or [verify all test cases](https://matl.suever.net/?code=jU%22%40%0AtZl%3AW%26%5C5ME%2a%2Bs&inputs=2+3+7+12+333+512&version=20.6.0).

#### Explanation

Consider input `12` as an example.

```
t     % Implicit input. Duplicate
      % STACK: 12, 12
Zl    % Binary logarithm
      % STACK: 12, 3.584962500721156
:     % Range (rounds down)
      % STACK: 12, [1 2 3]
W     % Power with base 2, element-wise
      % STACK: 12, [2 4 8]
&\    % 2-output modulus, element-wise: pushes remainders and quotients
      % STACK: [0 0 4], [6 3 1]
5M    % Push array of powers of 2, again
      % STACK: [0 0 4], [6 3 1], [2 4 8]
E     % Multiply by 2
      % STACK: [0 0 4], [6 3 1], [4 8 16]
*     % Multiply, element-wise
      % STACK: [0 0 4], [24 24 16]
+     % Add, element-wise
      % STACK: [24 24 20]
s     % Sum of array. Implicit display
      % STACK: 68
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
¢¬£¢iYTÃÅxÍ
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=oqyjomlZVMPFeM0=&input=ODg4)

---

### Explanation

```
                 :Implicit input of integer U
¢                :Convert to base-2 string
 ¬               :Split to an array of individual characters/digits
  £    Ã         :Map over the elements, with Y being the current 0-based index
   ¢             :  Convert U to a base-2 string
    iYT          :  Insert a 0 in that string at index Y
        Å        :Slice off the first element of the array
          Í      :Convert each element to a base-10 integer
         x       :Reduce by addition
```

Answer (score 4):

## C,  <s>58</s>  56 bytes

*Thanks to @Dennis for saving two bytes!*

```c
s,k;f(n){for(s=0,k=2;k<=n;k*=2)s+=n/k*k*2+n%k;return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYxBCsIwEEX3PUUoFGbSiJoiLsa5iRuJRsrgKEldlZ49Ftwa//I/3gubewilZCcUQXGOzwSZd07Yk5xYSSx7zD3rVqxY32snlG7TO6nJtJRRJ/O4jArYzI1Z90rrFaHtrmdtnYngEek3GarkWCX7P7mhHjx8vaV8AA)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 50 bytes

```c
s,k;f(n){for(s=0,k=2;k<=n;)s+=n%k+n/k*(k+=k);k=s;}
```

Returning by `k=s;` is undefined behaviour, but works with gcc when optimizations are disabled. Also, `n%k+n/k*(k+=k)` has [unspecified behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior), but seems to work fine with gcc.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYxBCsIwEEX3PUUoFGZMRG2RLsa5STcSiYTBUZruSs8eA90a//I/3vPHp/c5JycUQHEN7xkSn51wT3JjJUyWtROrJzmAWBYk4URbjrqY1z0qYLM2puwzlytA2z0mbZ0J0CPSbzJUyVgllz@5oR687t6Wvw)

Comment: `s,k;f(n){for(s=0,k=2;k<=n;)s+=n%k+n/k*(k*=2);return s;}` (55 bytes)

Comment: There's no telling which one gets evaluated first `n%k` or `n/k*(k*=2)`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Which side is evaluated first is left unspecified. C is like that...

Comment: Ah, I see you've added that in your answer indeed. Didn't knew this kind of undefined behavior happened in C. I have like three hours experience in C, so I barely know anything about it. TIL :) In Java `for(s=0,k=2;k<=n;)s+=n%k+n/k*(k*=2);return s;` is completely fine, and `n%k` will always be evaluated before `n/k*(k*=2)` and `n/k` will also evaluate before `k*=2`. Thanks for the explanation. (I will delete some of my comments now to reduce the clutter.)

Comment: I love using UB as a feature. And code golfing in a real life language should be in another category anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>20 15</s> 14 bytes

```
+/@}:@:+[\&.#:
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT0Fb36HWysFKOzpGTU/Z6n9qcka@QppCallqUaWCkYKxgrmCIZAyNlYwNTT6DwA)

#### 15 bytes

```
1#.-,+:-#.\.@#:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT8FQWU9XR9tKV1kvRs9B2ep/anJGvkKaQmpZalGlgpGCsYK5giGQMjZWMDU0@g8A)

```
     +:             Input×2
       -            Subtract
        #.\.@#:     The list of binary suffixes of input (in decimal)
   -,               Append negative input
1#.                 Add them up
```

Comment: why does the double minus formula work?  why is it equivalent to dilutions?

Comment: @Jonah dilution is adding a certain binary prefix (number "rounded down") to the number, which is equivalent to adding the whole number to itself (both prefix and the remainder) and then subtracting the remainder.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
BḊḄÐƤạḤS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/p4Y6uhztaDk84tuThroUPdywJ/n90z@H2R01r3P//N9JRMNZRMNdRMASxjIFsU0MjAA)

```
B                        to binary          42 -> 1 0 1 0 1 0
 Ḋ                       drop first                 0 1 0 1 0
  ḄÐƤ                    each suffix to decimal   10 10 2 2 0
      Ḥ                  double the input                  84
     ạ                   absolute difference   74 74 82 82 84
       S                 add them up                      396
```

Vice versa, `B¹ƤṖ+BḄS`: get prefixes, drop last, add them to input, and sum.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>41</s> 40 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to Mr.Xcoder*

```js
f=(n,k=1)=>k<n&&(n&k)+2*(n&~k)+f(n,k-~k)
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(n,k=1)=>k<n&&(n&k)+2*(n&~k)+f(n,k-~k)

console.log(f(2  )) //    4
console.log(f(3  )) //    5
console.log(f(7  )) //   24
console.log(f(12 )) //   68
console.log(f(333)) // 5128
console.log(f(512)) // 9216
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>53</s> <s>50</s> 47 bytes

```
.+
*
+`(_+)\1
$1O
O_
_
L$`\B
$`O$'
+%`\B
¶$`¶
_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9Pm0uLSztBI15bM8aQS8XQn8s/niuey0clIcaJSyXBX0WdS1sVxD60TSXh0Dau@P//jbiMucy5DIGUsTGXqaERAA) Link includes test cases. Edit: Saved 3 bytes thanks to @MartinEnder. Explanation:

```
.+
*
+`(_+)\1
$1O
O_
_
```

Convert from decimal to binary, but using O to represent 0, as it's not a digit, and _ to represent 1, as it's the default repetition character in Retina 1.

```
L$`\B
$`O$'
```

Insert an O between each pair of digits, and collect the results as a list.

```
+%`\B
¶$`¶
```

Convert from binary to unary. (This conversion produces extra `O`s, but we don't care.)

```
_
```

Sum and convert to decimal.

Comment: Binary to decimal conversion can be done in 12 bytes (saving 3): https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS4tLO0EjXlszxpBLxdCfyz@eK54rxonLX0WJy1HXMIFLWzUByD20TSXBiiv@/39DIwA See [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102263/8478) for how it works.

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks, I keep forgetting about that. (I was also slightly disappointed that the alternative version only works on a single number.)

Comment: Well, in the case where you've got each number on its own line you can make it work with an additional `%`. If it's more complicated you'd need something like `/[O_]+/_`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 13 bytes

```
smiXd.BQZ2Ssl
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=smiXd.BQZ2Ssl&input=333&debug=0)**

#### Explanation

```
smiXd.BQZ2Ssl | Full program.

           sl | The base-2 logarithm of the input, floored to an integer.
          S   | Create the integer range [1 ... the floored logarithm].
 m            | And map a function over it.
------------+-+-----------------------------------------------------
  iXd.BQZ2  | The function to be mapped (uses a variable d).
     .BQ    | In the binary representation of the input...
   X    Z   | ... Insert a zero...
    d       | ... At index d.
  i      2  | And convert the result from base 2 to an integer.
------------+-+-----------------------------------------------------
s             | Sum the resulting list.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
BµLḤ_J’×µḄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//QsK1TOG4pF9K4oCZw5fCteG4hP///zEy)

Not the shortest currently, but it could be if there's a way around `Bµ µḄ`...

#### Explanation

```
BµLḤ_J’×µḄ    Main link. Argument: n (integer)
B             Binary; convert n to an binary of binary digits. Call this A.
 µ            Start a new monadic link with argument A.
  L           Length; yield len(A). We'll call this l.
   Ḥ          Unhalve; yield l * 2.
     J        Length range; yield [1, 2, ..., l].
    _         Subtract; yield [l*2 - 1, l*2 - 2, ..., l].
      ’       Decrement; subtract one from each item.
       ×      Multiply each item by the corresponding item in A. Call this B.
        µ     Start a new monadic link with argument B.
         Ḅ    Unbinary; convert from a binary array to a decimal.
```

Basically, this works by multiplying each binary digit by a magic number. I can't explain it without visualizing it, so here's the binary number we'll be working with:

```
1111
```

As explained by the challenge, he output we want is the sum of these binary numbers:

```
10111  = 2^4 + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0
11011  = 2^4 + 2^3 + 2^1 + 2^0
11101  = 2^4 + 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^0
```

However, we don't actually have to insert zeroes: Jelly's "unbinary" atom will accept numbers other than just `0` and `1`. When we allow ourselves to use `2`, this pattern gets simpler:

```
2111   = 2*2^3 + 1*2^2 + 1*2^1 + 1*2^0
2211   = 2*2^3 + 2*2^2 + 1*2^1 + 1*2^0
2221   = 2*2^3 + 2*2^2 + 2*2^1 + 1*2^0
```

When we sum up the digits in each column, we get

```
6543   = 6*2^3 + 5*2^2 + 4*2^1 + 3*2^0 = 48 + 20 + 8 + 3 = 79.
```

The trick this answer uses is to generate this pattern, and multiply each digit by the corresponding digit in the original to cancel out the necessary columns. 12, for example, would be represented as

```
 1100
×6543
=6500  = 6*2^3 + 5*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 0*2^0 = 48 + 20 + 0 + 0 = 68.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @Mr. Xcoder!

```
ṁḋ§z·+Θḣotṫḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxoc7ug8trzq0XfvcjIc7FueXPNy5Gij0//9/Y2NjAA)

#### Explanation

```
ṁḋ§z·+Θḣ(tṫ)ḋ  -- example input: 6
            ḋ  -- convert to binary: [1,1,0]
  §            -- fork argument
        (tṫ)   -- | tail of tails: [[1,0],[0]]
       ḣ       -- | heads: [[1],[1,1],[1,1,0]]
   z           -- and zipWith the following (example with [1,0] [1])
    · Θ        -- | prepend 0 to second argument: [0,1]
     +         -- | concatenate: [1,0,0,1]
               -- : [[1,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0]]
ṁ              -- map the following (example with [1,0,1,0]) and sum
 ḋ             -- | convert from binary: 10
               -- : 22
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 55 bytes

```
n->{int r=0,i=2;for(;i<=n;r+=n%i+n/i*(i*=2));return r;}
```

Port of [Steadybox' C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154310/52210), and golfed 3 bytes in the process.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hY67DsIwDEV3vsILUsqjvIQYQvgDujAihpCmyKW4VZpWQlW@vaQ8ViLZlnyvda5z2cp5WWnK03uvClnXcJRI3QgAyWqTSaUhGda3AIoNkyLuFefbV22lRQUJEAjoaX7ohhMjljMUa56VhnHcC@JmKmiMU1rghOFErKOIG20bQ2C46/kHVjXXwsO@zLbEFB7@H3ayBul2vsjo88vpWVv9iMvGxpV3bEGMYsUG6D9/E/B3AX8VDNiEIrY/hhu5/gU)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>141</s> 48 bytes

```r
function(n,l=2^(1:log2(n)))sum(n%%l+(n%/%l*2*l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcQxCoAwDADAva9wKSS1ok23ol8RRIgIMRWrg6@v3nBX5WbsKj@63ntWUC8TzRCS5I1AEbE8B6i10v73Vhw5QawMgdAwxBjRlOU85QVKYfCM9QM)

<s>Either I'm doing something really wrong or R is just terrible at bit manipulation.</s> Porting [Luis Mendo's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154311/67312) is easy, correct, and golfy.

But if you really just want to muck around with bit operations, [MickyT](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31347) suggested the following 105 byter:

```r
function(i)sum(sapply(1:max(which(b<-intToBits(i)>0)),function(x)packBits(head(append(b,F,x),-1),"i")))-i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1BCoMwEEX3PUVxNQMTMIZuRLrooifwAjEaMrTG0EQaT59qKV19Pv89/qvYcyeKXb1JvHhgjOsMUYfw3EC2s87wdmwcDJ1gn/rlxinu1LVGpL@VMWjz@E5u0iPs@uRHGOhOGUlIpIorRBRcLMgGTxaUUkdcjva7a1pZk8XyAQ)

Comment: Here's a [111 byte](https://tio.run/##PY1BDsIgFET3nsJ09X/ySUqJG9O46MITeAFKQYiWkkIjnh6pi64mk5k3sxZz7lkxm1fJLR4cxm2GKEN4f6G7zjLDxzplYeyZ8@mxDC7F2rq1iIzTwWUMUr3@odVygjqg/QQj3SkjMY7UVFw/9dogYjHAOzwZEELsctndccpbMlh@) one that I'm sure you could take a few more out of.

Comment: @MickyT Cheers! very nice, although porting an entirely different approach is better!

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>92</s> <s>80</s> 78 bytes

```
def b(x):x=f'{x:b}';return sum(int(x[:i]+'0'+x[i:],2)for i in range(1,len(x)))
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFJo0LTqsI2Tb26wiqpVt26KLWktChPobg0VyMzr0SjItoqM1Zb3UBduyI60ypWx0gzLb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVXDUCcnNQ9ohqbm/4IikI4kDSNNTS4Y2xiJbY7ENkRRZIyszBQk9x8A)

Thanks to [Mr.XCoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder) and [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs) for -12 bytes and -2 bytes respectively.

Comment: [80 bytes](https://tio.run/##VctBCsIwEIXhvaeYXWdoFzZBhIgnCVk0mOqATktMIZ4@NQsh7j54718/6bGILuUWZvCYyeSrZ/nCKuMuMaQtCry3F7IkzNaw67tj12fLxg2K5iUCAwvESe4Bx@EZakxU1lgLj4ro8LNufG48/p10ezvVrew "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
.²LoDŠ‰ø`r·*+O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f79Amn3yXowseNWw4vCOh6NB2LW3///8NjQA)

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, <s>92</s> 77 bytes

```
@set/an=2,t=0
:l
@if %1 geq %n% set/at+=%1*2-(%1%%n),n*=2&goto l
@echo %t%
```

Edit: Switched to the same formula everyone else is using.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>21</s> 18 bytes

```
2*a-a%2**_MS1,#TBa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@F/930grUTdR1UhLK9432FBHOcQp8X@tgi9XNJeCEZeCMZeCOZeCIYhlDGSbAlmx///r5gEA)

#### Explanation

Call our input number `a`. For each binary index `i` at which we want to insert a zero, we can calculate the bits left of the insertion point as `a // 2**i` (where `//` is integer division and `**` is exponentiation), the bits right of the insertion point as `a % 2**i`, and therefore the diluted integer as `2 * (a // 2**i) * 2**i + (a % 2**i)`. But `(a // 2**i) * 2**i` is equal to `a - (a % 2**i)`, and so we can rearrange to a shorter formula: `2 * (a - a % 2**i) + a % 2**i` = `2 * a - a % 2**i`.

```
2*a-a%2**_MS1,#TBa
                       a is 1st command-line argument (implicit)
               TBa     Convert a to binary
              #        Length of the binary expansion
            1,         Range from 1 up to (but not including) that number
          MS           Map this function to the range and sum the results:
2*a-a%2**_              The above formula, where _ is the argument of the function
                       The final result is autoprinted
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
BLḊṬœṗ¥€Bj€0ḄS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/J5@GOroc71xyd/HDn9ENLHzWtccoCEgYPd7QE////39TQCAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 36 + 1 (`-p`) = 37 bytes

```perl
$\+=$_*2-($_&$.-1)while($.*=2)<=$_}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lRttWJV7LSFdDJV5NRU/XULM8IzMnVUNFT8vWSNMGKFdb/f@/sbHxv/yCksz8vOL/ugUA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), 57 bytes

```
Sum##UnBin=>{Join[Join=>_,"0"]}=>SplitAt#1&`:@{#_-1}##Bin
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3vkpqWmZcarZKm8z@4NFdZOTTPKTPP1q7aKz8zLxpE2NrF6ygZKMXW2toFF@RkljiWKBuqJVg5VCvH6xrWKisDlf@P5QooyswrUbC1UwBpUVNS0LVTUAJxw5TTQFS0kY6CsY6CuY6CIYhlDGSbGhrF/gcA)

I thought I'd approach the problem from a non-bit manipulation approach, as such an approach is impractical in Attache. I have to investigate some of the parts of this approach for alternatives.

### Explanation

Here is an expanded version:

```
Define[$joinByZero, {Join[Join=>_,"0"]}]

Define[$insertionPoints,
    SplitAt#1&`:@{#_-1}
]

Define[$f,
Sum##UnBin=>joinByZero=>insertionPoints##Bin
]
```

This simply takes the binary representation of the number, splits it at certain points, inserts zeroes there, converts back to decimal, and sums them together.

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 33 bytes

```
1#.[:}:#.@(<\;@(,0;])"0<@}.\.)@#:
```

Most probably there is much room for further golfing.

### How?

`@#:` convert to binary and

`<@}.\.` - find all suffices, drop the first digit from each and box

`<\`  - find all prefixes and box them

`(,0;])"0` - to each prefix append 0 then append the corresponding beheaded suffix

`;@` raze (unbox)

`1#.[:}:#.@` - convert to decimal, curtail and sum

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZX1oq1qrZT1HDRsYqwdNHQMrGM1lQxsHGr1YvQ0HZSt/mtyKXClJmfkK6QppJalFlUqGCkYK5grGAIpY2MFU0Oj/wA)